# SodiumChachaIetf::decrypt() must be of the type string, boolean

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, helper, register

I did migration **Magento 1 to Magento 2.3.0** all is good but when I create customer form both of side (front and admin) I got the error related to decrypt even I can not edit the customer when I click on save same error has occurred.

Below error is :

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of
> Magento\Framework\Encryption\Adapter\SodiumChachaIetf::decrypt() must
> be of the type string, boolean returned in
> public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Adapter/SodiumChachaIetf.php:68
> Stack trace: #0
> public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php(358):
> Magento\Framework\Encryption\Adapter\SodiumChachaIetf->decrypt('"\x10\x88\x8E\xB5\x851;H\xB1\x12\xE1aaP...')
>
> **#1 /public_html/vendor/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension/Helper/Data.php(744):**
> Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor->decrypt('IhCIjrWFMTtIsRL...')
>
> **#2 /public_html/vendor/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension/Helper/Data.php(203):**
> Dotdigitalgroup\Email\Helper\Data->getApiPassword(Object(Magento\Store\Model\Website\Interceptor))
>
> **#3 public_html/vendor/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extens
> in**
> /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Adapter/SodiumChachaIetf.php on line 68

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Go to Below file:

> vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Adapter/SodiumChachaIetf.php

**And Update Below Code on `decrypt()` method:**

```php
$plainText = sodium_crypto_aead_chacha20poly1305_ietf_decrypt(
    $payload,
    $nonce,
    $nonce,
    $this->key
);

return $plainText ?: '';
```

Comment: Do not edit core files.

Comment: Above solution from magento issue discussion https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19590

Comment: this fixed it for me, but what is the issue?  Is this just a known bug?

Answer (score 15):

Looks like you are using the wrong crypt key.

You should keep the key from your previews configuration:

app/etc/local.xml [Magento 1.x]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <global>
    <install>
      <date>{{date}}</date>
    </install>
    <crypt>
       <key>123456_same_old_key_7890</key>
    </crypt>
[...]
```

And replace the new one in the new project:

app/etc/env.php  [Magento 2.x]

```
<?php
[...],
'crypt' => [
    'key' => '123456_same_old_key_7890'
],
[...]
```

Source: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19590

Comment: This happen to me after copy database from server to local, copying also key help in that keys.

Comment: perfect answer with explanation!!! made my day :) +1

Answer (score 7):

Modifying the core class is not recommended at all. The issue is not with the class `vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Adapter/SodiumChachaIetf.php`

But the issue with the **crypt key** added to your `app/etc/env.php`

The reason of this issue is the crypt key is mismatched. You must have taken the database dump from any other instance and trying to run with your current instance. So along with database you need to get the **crypt key** from the same setup where from you got the db dump.

Just update the **crypt key** in **env.php** and it will work fine.

The fix is to use same crypt key of the installation from where db is being used.

Hope it is explained.

Mark me up if was helpful. Happy coding..!!

Comment: This solved the issue for me and was referenced in the Magento github issue (https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19590#issuecomment-458731483). I think this should be the correct answer

Comment: Just removed crypt key and it helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Go to this file:

> vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Adapter/SodiumChachaIetf.php

And update below code:

```
 public function decrypt(string $data): string
    {
        $nonce = mb_substr($data, 0, SODIUM_CRYPTO_AEAD_CHACHA20POLY1305_IETF_NPUBBYTES, '8bit');
        $payload = mb_substr($data, SODIUM_CRYPTO_AEAD_CHACHA20POLY1305_IETF_NPUBBYTES, null, '8bit');

        $plainText = sodium_crypto_aead_chacha20poly1305_ietf_decrypt(
            $payload,
            $nonce,
            $nonce,
            $this->key
        );

        return (string) $plainText;
    }
```

Just change the function return type:
 From

```
return $plainText
```

to

```
return (string) $plainText
```

Comment: Worked for me..!

Answer (score 3):

More an FYI still in 2.3 develop branch.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Encryption/Adapter/SodiumChachaIetf.php

Official magento fix is this

```
    /**
     * Decrypt a string
     *
     * @param string $data
     * @return string
     */
    public function decrypt(string $data): string
    {
        $nonce = mb_substr($data, 0, SODIUM_CRYPTO_AEAD_CHACHA20POLY1305_IETF_NPUBBYTES, '8bit');
        $payload = mb_substr($data, SODIUM_CRYPTO_AEAD_CHACHA20POLY1305_IETF_NPUBBYTES, null, '8bit');
        try {
            $plainText = sodium_crypto_aead_chacha20poly1305_ietf_decrypt(
                $payload,
                $nonce,
                $nonce,
                $this->key
            );
        } catch (\SodiumException $e) {
            $plainText = '';
        }
        return $plainText !== false ? $plainText : '';
    }
```