# php bin/magento setup:upgrade issue

Tags: magento2.3, setup-upgrade

**Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Framework\Locale\Resolver**

when I run this command this error shows. I am using third party theme.

Already tried deleting generated and var/di [image]

Comment: check your system.log from var/log/system.log. Here you can find the issue

Comment: Deleting var/generation, var/cache and var/di and try

Comment: already done deleting now it stop even showing any error

Comment: run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f now it will generate again

Comment: nothing no result

Comment: see the updated question

Comment: If you did some changes try to `run di:compile` and check

Comment: i merged the third party theme

Comment: still same error using di:compile

Comment: check the updated question after using `composer update` and `di:compile`

Comment: please up-vote the question if you dont have answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have searched around and found this solution this is because of `return $plainText`  **SodiumChachaIetf::decrypt() must be of the type string, boolean**

Go to this file:

> vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Adapter/SodiumChachaIetf.php

**And Update Below Code:**

```
$plainText = sodium_crypto_aead_chacha20poly1305_ietf_decrypt(
            $payload,
            $nonce,
            $nonce,
            $this->key
        );
        if ($plainText == false)
        {
          return "";
        }
        return $plainText;
```

Answer (score 17):

The fix for the issue -

> Type Error occurred when creating the object: Magento\Framework\Locale\Resolver

is not modifying the core class at all. We need to understand the cause of it first. Modifying the core class is not recommended at all. The issue is not with the class `vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Adapter/SodiumChachaIetf.php`

⚠️ But the issue with the **crypt key** added to your `app/etc/env.php`

The reason for this issue is the crypt key is mismatched. You must have taken the database dump from any other instance and trying to run with your current instance. So along with the database, you need to get the **crypt key** from the same setup where from you got the DB dump.

Just update the **crypt key** in **env.php** and it will work fine.

The fix is to use the same pair of crypt keys of the installation from where DB is being used.

Hope it is explained.

Mark me up if was helpful. Happy coding..!!

Comment: It works if you clear the value in env.php too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that you are using the proper crypt key for the database used? Magento's Encryption process will not work if the crypt used for encryption in the database is different than the one declared in the env.php file.

If you have no idea where to get the proper crypt file, you may copy the crypt hash from the magento instance that dumped the database that you are using.

Clear your cache afterwards by deleting them manually.

Answer (score 0):

Different key to what was in place when you installed site against what's now in place will cause this issue

Once lost no way to get back

Will only affect handful of extensions that rely on reversible encryption

Magento solution is this

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/278420/70343

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved it by adding a typecase when returning the variable.

File: vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Adapter/SodiumChachaIetf.php

```
 /**
 * Decrypt a string
 *
 * @param string $data
 * @return string
 */
public function decrypt(string $data): string
{
    $nonce = mb_substr($data, 0, SODIUM_CRYPTO_AEAD_CHACHA20POLY1305_IETF_NPUBBYTES, '8bit');
    $payload = mb_substr($data, SODIUM_CRYPTO_AEAD_CHACHA20POLY1305_IETF_NPUBBYTES, null, '8bit');

    $plainText = sodium_crypto_aead_chacha20poly1305_ietf_decrypt(
        $payload,
        $nonce,
        $nonce,
        $this->key
    );

    return (string) $plainText; // <- Add the typecase (string) before the variable
}
```